# non-unique index for datetime and ip address for mysql select

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I would like to set correct indexes for this query:
`select id from table where datetime>='2016-02-24 12:04:05' and ip_address = '192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.1.'` (my php scrpt identifies IPs with multiple ways)

Then I would like to create index to speed thing up - create non-unique index myindex(datetime, ip_address) - is this the right index?

Or maybe should I create md5 hash of ip and store it in separate db in column hashed_ipaddress? And use this hash with datetime to select lines? "create non-unique index myindex(datetime, hashed_ipaddress)"?

Comment: It seems to me that you could test the alternatives in the time it takes to ask the question.

Comment: Yes, this is one option. But maybe people with much more experiences than me could advice, what is the best way to go.